# Creating a function to deal with navbar

Tags: php, arrays, function, dynamic

so let me start off by explaining what im trying to make.

I'm trying to make a function called create_navbar_simple, all this function does it make the html layout of a navigation bar, a simple one which is just anchor tag after anchor tag (which is separately styled to look like buttons, outside the function, irrelevant). now.. the point is, in the header i can just call create_navbar_simple(), and insert my button names inside the parameter, like so:
create_navbar_simple("home","about us","contact us") ... and so on.

Now that would be simple enough, in fact i have already created something like this:
function

```
create_navbar_simple($button1,$button2,$button3,$button4,$button5,$button6,$button7,$button8,$button9,$button10){
    //creates a simple li structured navbar
    <a href="link">$button1></a>
}
```

Now that would obviously create the navbar with those amount of buttons, but now i am trying to take it 1 step further, i want it so that it will function and create the correct amount of buttons, without know how many arguments i enter in the function , ie. works with any amount of numbers, i would like to preferable replace all those variables in the parameters with an array? and somehow work with that?

Help would be appreciated, and im not fussed if its not such a good idea or anything like that, i would probably not use it in a real site anyway, im just practician.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling your function:

```
create_navbar_simple(array('page1', 'page2', '...'));
```

declaring your function:

```
function create_navbar_simple($pages) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        echo $page;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is exactly the method i was looking for , to tackle this solution, thanks alot.